# How can I tell when/what is loading certain Assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem with an invalidCastException noted here:

[InvalidCastException thrown after install on new machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811855/invalidcastexception-thrown-after-install-on-new-machine)

After some research, I've used the following code to determine what assemblies have been loaded:

```
        AppDomain MyDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        Assembly[] AssembliesLoaded = MyDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (Assembly MyAssembly in AssembliesLoaded)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loaded: {0}", MyAssembly.FullName);
        }
```

That shows me that two assemblies of the program I am working on are loaded.  I'm not sure how this occurs, as it doesn't occur on any other machine.  Can I tell how/where this assembly is loaded so I can fix it?

Comment: Try this: [`AppDomain.AssemblyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is to use [Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).